# Sql When A = Z then set B = X

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I cant seem to get this query to run, it keeps telling me "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near '='." Not sure what i doing wrong here.

Basically i need [forwarder_preferred_status] to be P2 or P3 depending on the value of [forwarder_short]

Any Suggestions would be welcome

```
        Select 
            [forwarder_display],
            Case [forwarder_preferred_status]
            -- Update P2 Customers
                When [forwarder_short] = 'ABL' THEN [forwarder_preferred_status] = 'P2'
                When [forwarder_short] = 'ALK' THEN [forwarder_preferred_status] = 'P2'
                When [forwarder_short] = 'EIF' THEN [forwarder_preferred_status] = 'P2'
                When [forwarder_short] = 'NNR' THEN [forwarder_preferred_status] = 'P2'
                When [forwarder_short] = 'ALI' THEN [forwarder_preferred_status] = 'P2'
                When [forwarder_short] = 'LAF' THEN [forwarder_preferred_status] = 'P2'
                When [forwarder_short] = 'AIT' THEN [forwarder_preferred_status] = 'P2'
            -- Update P3 Customers
                When [forwarder_short] = 'SCHBAX' THEN [forwarder_preferred_status] = 'P3'
                When [forwarder_short] = 'UPS' THEN [forwarder_preferred_status] = 'P3'
                When [forwarder_short] = 'KUE' THEN [forwarder_preferred_status] = 'P3'
                When [forwarder_short] = 'AGI' THEN [forwarder_preferred_status] = 'P3'
                When [forwarder_short] = 'PAN' THEN [forwarder_preferred_status] = 'P3'
                When [forwarder_short] = 'DGF' THEN [forwarder_preferred_status] = 'P3'
                When [forwarder_short] = 'NEC' THEN [forwarder_preferred_status] = 'P3'
                When [forwarder_short] = 'HWE' THEN [forwarder_preferred_status] = 'P3'
                When [forwarder_short] = 'NIS' THEN [forwarder_preferred_status] = 'P3'
                When [forwarder_short] = 'BDP' THEN [forwarder_preferred_status] = 'P3'
                When [forwarder_short] = 'KWE' THEN [forwarder_preferred_status] = 'P3'
                When [forwarder_short] = 'CEVA' THEN [forwarder_preferred_status] = 'P3'
                When [forwarder_short] = 'VIZ' THEN [forwarder_preferred_status] = 'P3'
                When [forwarder_short] = 'FTN' THEN [forwarder_preferred_status] = 'P3'
                When [forwarder_short] = 'UTI' THEN [forwarder_preferred_status] = 'P3'
            -- Fix wrong prefered status
                When [forwarder_short] = 'OIA' THEN [forwarder_preferred_status] = null
                When [forwarder_short] = 'PHO' THEN [forwarder_preferred_status] = null
                When [forwarder_short] = 'REI' THEN [forwarder_preferred_status] = null
                Else [forwarder_preferred_status]
            End as [forwarder_preferred_status]
            Sum ([calc_gross_rev]) As [Gr Revenue]
            Sum ([charge_weight]) As [Ch Weight]
        From 
            [dbo].[report_bo_awb_revenue_all]

        Where 
            [yr] = 2014
            AND [agent_iata_code] not in ('0508634','0514616')
```

Comment: Your CASE has a syntax error - you don't want `Case [forwarder_preferred_status]` just use `CASE` there because you have comparison in each `WHEN`. Plus many other issues.  What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Add commas "," between the items in the select-list. And also a GROUP BY clause, since you are doing some SUM's.

Comment: Why don't you create a table that maps these relations instead of writing a 50-line CASE expression with hard-coded constants?

Comment: You can also use IN instead of many WHENs
WHEN [forwarder_short] IN ('SCHBAX', ...) THAN [forwarder_preferred_status] = 'P3'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in your question is structured like this:

```
--Bad
CASE A
    WHEN X THEN A = B
    WHEN Y THEN A = C
    ...
END
```

Instead, you need to structure it like this:

```
--Good
A = CASE
       WHEN X THEN B
       WHEN Y THEN C 
       ...
    END
```

or like this:

```
--Good
CASE
   WHEN X THEN B
   WHEN Y THEN C 
   ...
END As A
```

A case statement only results in a *value*, not an expression. It doesn't branch between arbitrary code. Also, given you have a lot of codes that result in the same value, you can *greatly* simplifiy things like this:

```
--Better
CASE
   WHEN X IN (1,2,3) THEN B
   WHEN X IN (4,5,6) THEN C
   ...
   ELSE NULL
END
```

That would look something like this:

```
Select 
    [forwarder_display],
    CASE 
        WHEN [forwarder_short] IN ('ABL', 'ALK', 'EIF', 'NNR', 'ALI', 'LAF', 'AIT')
          THEN 'P2' 
        WHEN [forwarder_short] IN ('SCHBAX', 'UPS', 'KUE', 'AGI', 'PAN', 'DGF', 'NEC', 
                                   'HWE', 'NIS', 'BDP', 'KWE', 'CEVA', 'VIZ', 'FTN', 'UTI') 
           THEN 'P3'
        WHEN [forwarder_short] IN ('OIA','PHO', 'REI')
           THEN NULL
        ELSE [forwarder_preferred_status]
    END as [forwarder_preferred_status],
    Sum ([calc_gross_rev]) As [Gr Revenue],
    Sum ([charge_weight]) As [Ch Weight]
From 
    [dbo].[report_bo_awb_revenue_all]

Where 
    [yr] = 2014
    AND [agent_iata_code] not in ('0508634','0514616')
```

Unfortunately, this still won't work, as you're missing the GROUP BY clause needed to make your `SUM()` aggregate functions work. Because of the complex expressions, I find it easier to fix the problem by nesting the query, like this:

```
SELECT forwarder_display, [forwarder_preferred_status],
    SUM([calc_gross_rev]) As [Gr Revenue],
    SUM([charge_weight]) As [Ch Weight]
FROM 
(
    Select 
        [forwarder_display], 
        CASE 
            WHEN [forwarder_short] IN ('ABL', 'ALK', 'EIF', 'NNR', 'ALI', 'LAF', 'AIT')
              THEN 'P2' 
            WHEN [forwarder_short] IN ('SCHBAX', 'UPS', 'KUE', 'AGI', 'PAN', 'DGF', 'NEC', 
                                       'HWE', 'NIS', 'BDP', 'KWE', 'CEVA', 'VIZ', 'FTN', 'UTI') 
               THEN 'P3'
            WHEN [forwarder_short] IN ('OIA','PHO', 'REI')
               THEN NULL
            ELSE [forwarder_preferred_status]
        END as [forwarder_preferred_status],
        [calc_gross_rev],
        [charge_weight]
    From 
        [dbo].[report_bo_awb_revenue_all]

    Where 
        [yr] = 2014
        AND [agent_iata_code] not in ('0508634','0514616')
) t
GROUP BY [forwarder_display], [forwarder_preferred_status]
```

This should run and give you the desired results, barring some mistake (very likely, given that I've typed all this untested into the answer window). However, you may find you get a better execution plan by just copy/pasting the complex CASE expression to the GROUP BY clause, with no nested query.

Lastly, code like this — with all of those 3 and 4 -digit codes hard-coded in — cries out to have these codes put into a table, such that this is done via a JOIN + COALESCE, rather than a CASE. That would be **MUCH** better for both performance and maintenance. That would allow you to write something like this:

```
--Best
SELECT [forwarder_display],
    COALESCE(M.status, A.forwarder_preferred_status) As forwarder_preferred_status
    Sum ([calc_gross_rev]) As [Gr Revenue],
    Sum ([charge_weight]) As [Ch Weight]
FROM [dbo].[report_bo_awb_revenue_all] A
LEFT JOIN forwarder_map M ON m.forwarder_short = A.forwarder_short
WHERE
    A.[yr] = 2014
    AND [agent_iata_code] not in ('0508634','0514616')
GROUP BY [forwarder_display], COALESCE(M.status, A.forwarder_preferred_status)
```

One final note: for the example above to work, you would need to use empty strings instead of NULL values in the imaginary `forwarder_map` table. You could then use the `NULLIF()` to get NULLs back, if that's really what you need.

Comment: any specific example detailing Good implementation of CASE?

Comment: @brykneval You may find [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) and [this post](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression) useful.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I mean those you marked --Good and got from Aaron

Comment: With the right column names, that could be real code.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to specify the field name in the `THEN` section of the `CASE` statement and you can remove the syntax before the first `WHEN` as the comparison is done in each `WHEN` clause:

```
CASE WHEN [forwarder_short] = 'ABL' THEN 'P2'...
End as [forwarder_preferred_status]
```

An alternative is to use an `IN` clause to save some characters:

```
CASE WHEN [forwarder_short] IN('ABL','ALK','EIF'...) THEN 'P2'...
End as [forwarder_preferred_status]
```

Answer (score 2):

You alias the column name *after* the `case` using `as` (or using `=` before the expression).  Something like this:

```
      (Case When [forwarder_short] = 'ABL' THEN 'P2'
            When [forwarder_short] = 'ALK' THEN 'P2'
            . . .
       End) as forwarder_preferred_status
```

or (as Aaron Bertrand prefers but I don't):

```
      forwarder_preferred_status = (Case When [forwarder_short] = 'ABL' THEN 'P2'
                                         When [forwarder_short] = 'ALK' THEN 'P2'
                                         . . .
                                    End);
```

In addition, your expression after the `case` is inconsistent with the use of boolean expressions in the `when`.  This is just sticking with the form of the case that uses boolean expressions.

You can greatly simplify your logic by using `in`:

```
        (case when forwarder_short in ('ABL', 'ALK', 'EIF', 'NNR', 'ALI', 'LAF', 'AIT')
              then 'P2'
              . . .
         end) as forwarder_preferred_status
```

Comment: ...or before. Preference.

Comment: @AaronBertrand why before or after alias?

Comment: I'm not saying you need to bow to my preference. Just commenting that it doesn't *have* to be after.

Comment: @brykneval you can alias in multiple ways - [here are my thoughts on it for SQL Server](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases.aspx); these don't necessarily translate to other platforms (or for standards-sticklers).

Answer (score 2):

Your statment is very difficult to read/edit... you can use a shorter/simpler way.. like this:

```
SELECT [forwarder_display],
      CASE 
        WHEN [forwarder_short] IN ('ABL','ALK','NNR','EIF','ALI','LAF','AIT') THEN 'P2' 
        WHEN [forwarder_short] IN ('SCHBAX', 'UPS', 'KUE','AGI','PAN'......) THEN 'P3'
        WHEN [forwarder_short] IN ('OIA','PHO','REI') THEN null
      ELSE [forwarder_preferred_status]
      END AS forwarder_preferred_status
      ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I bet this isn't the first time someone has needed to translate ABL to a P2 for a report and it won't be the last. As @Aaron pointed out, stop with these horrible case statements and tabularize it.

For the sake of this answer, I am using a table variable. These generally are not advisable as the database engine doesn't record any statistics about values in there and their distribution which is the key for it to make good query plans.

```
DECLARE
    @TRANSLATE table
(
    forwarder_short varchar(10) NOT NULL
,   forwarder_preferred_status varchar(10) NULL
);

INSERT INTO
    @TRANSLATE
(
    forwarder_short
,   forwarder_preferred_status
)
VALUES
    ('ABL', 'P2')
,   ('ALK', 'P2')
,   ('EIF', 'P2')
,   ('NNR', 'P2')
,   ('ALI', 'P2')
,   ('LAF', 'P2')
,   ('AIT', 'P2')
,   ('SCHBAX', 'P3')
,   ('UPS', 'P3')
,   ('KUE', 'P3')
,   ('AGI', 'P3')
,   ('PAN', 'P3')
,   ('DGF', 'P3')
,   ('NEC', 'P3')
,   ('HWE', 'P3')
,   ('NIS', 'P3')
,   ('BDP', 'P3')
,   ('KWE', 'P3')
,   ('CEVA', 'P3')
,   ('VIZ', 'P3')
,   ('FTN', 'P3')
,   ('UTI', 'P3')
,   ('OIA', NULL)
,   ('PHO', NULL)
,   ('REI', NULL);
```

Now I have a table, `TRANSLATE` that provides a mapping between our known `forwarder_short` values to a rollup `forwarder_preferred_status`.

To cover conditions where the forwarder_short values are not in this table, we need to use our translation table as an OUTER JOIN.

```
WITH report_bo_awb_revenue_all AS
(
    -- simulating your source data
    SELECT
        T.forwarder_short
    ,   T.forwarder_preferred_status
    ,   100 AS calc_gross_rev
    ,   12 AS charge_weigh
    ,   2014 AS yr
    ,   '' AS agent_iata_code
    ,   'fwd' AS forwarder_display
    FROM
        @TRANSLATE AS T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'UNK'
    ,   'P90x'
    ,   9000 AS calc_gross_rev
    ,   12 AS charge_weigh
    ,   2014 AS yr
    ,   '' AS agent_iata_code
    ,   'fwd' AS forwarder_display
)
SELECT
    R.forwarder_display
,   COALESCE(T.forwarder_preferred_status, R.forwarder_preferred_status) AS forwarder_preferred_status
,   SUM(R.calc_gross_rev) AS calc_gross_rev
,   SUM(R.charge_weigh) AS charge_weigh
FROM
    report_bo_awb_revenue_all AS R
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        @TRANSLATE AS T
        ON T.forwarder_short = R.forwarder_short
WHERE
    R.yr = 2014
    AND R.agent_iata_code not in ('0508634','0514616')
GROUP BY
    R.forwarder_display
,   T.forwarder_preferred_status
,   R.forwarder_preferred_status;
```

Now, all business logic is distilled down to this

```
,   COALESCE(T.forwarder_preferred_status, R.forwarder_preferred_status) AS forwarder_preferred_status
```

"Use the value in our translate table if it exists, otherwise, use what's stored on the report_bo_awb_revenue_all table."

[SQLFiddle version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/42150) This uses a temporary table for translation as the fiddle doesn't handle table variables but the core concept remains.